# How to get order info from 'my accounts > orders' page in Woocommerce? $order->get_id() does not match the order number

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

WordPress, WooCommerce, I am logged in and have purchased an order. The order number is 61. I have written some code to add a button that will email the admin to let them know I am requesting a refund for this order. Problem is that the order number I get back does not match that shown. I am new to coding so I am sure the error will be obvious to someone else. Could use your insight.

Here is my code. For testing, I am just displaying the values above the button.

```
 $Customer = $order->get_billing_first_name() . " " . $order->get_billing_last_name();
 $orderno = $order->get_id();
 foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $Product = $item->get_name();
    $pid = $order->get_id();
    $Amount = $order->get_formatted_order_total( );
    $status = $order->get_status();
 }

echo 'Customer: ' . $Customer . ' Order: ' . $orderno . ' Product: ' . $Product . " Order#" . $pid . ' Amount: '    . $Amount . " status: " .  $status;
```

[image: Order does not match]

Answer (score 0):

```
$customer = wp_get_current_user();
// Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(), // login user 
        'post_type' => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses()), 
        'post_status' => array('wc-processing'), // order status 
    ));

    $Order_Array = []; //
    foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) {
        $orderq = wc_get_order($customer_order);
        $Order_Array[] = [
            'ID' => $orderq->get_id(), //order id
            'Value' => $orderq->get_total(), // order value
            'Date' => $orderq->get_date_created()->date_i18n('Y-m-d'), //order date
        ];

    }
```